# Using ng-pattern to recognize leading zero in Angular alphanumeric field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, ng-pattern

How can I recognize a leading zero in an alphanumeric field using ng-pattern in angular?

```
  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Regex test</h1>
    <form name="myForm">
      <input name="myNumberField" ng-model="myNumber" ng-pattern="REGEX HERE" required/>
      <span ng-show="myForm.myNumberField.$error.pattern">Invalid pattern</span>
    </form>
  </body>
```

I tried `ng-pattern="/(^0[0-9].*$)/"` and `ng-pattern="/(^0.*$)/"`

**Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/laB3Q7nApuoLT9NYnCGX?p=preview**

For example:

**Invalid Patterns:**

0AHFFB

00AJFH

0038429347

**Valid Patterns:**

AHFFB

AJFBN

32400342

30292900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-pattern="/(^[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$)/"
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Comment: This almost works but it throws an error for letters as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the expression:

```
^(?:\w|[1-9])(?:\w|\d)+$
```

It reads:

- start from the beginning of the string
- accept a character that is either a word character \w or 1 to 9
- accept any number of word characters or digits (including 0)
- end of string

Test it on https://regex101.com/